# Как настроить выделение переменной двойным щелчком в Sublime Text 3?

Tags: php, sublime-text, sublime-text-3

При нажатии двойным щелчком мыши на переменную выделяется только ее название без знака $, что для меня совсем неудобно. Можно ли как-нибудь настроить Sublime,чтобы он выделял ее полностью? Пишу на php/javascript/css/html

Comment: Открываете настройки:
Preferences > Settings, ищите "word_separators"
копируете ее в раздел настроек пользователя, удаляете от туда символ доллара.
Ну или просто скопируйте и вставте строку что я привел как пример.

"word_separators": "./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#%^&*|+=[]{}`~?". А вообще работайте в IDE (PHPStorm например)

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Comment: Я оформлю ответ, поставьте мне галочку в карму

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Открываете настройки: Preferences > Settings, ищите "word_separators" копируете ее в раздел настроек пользователя, удаляете от туда символ доллара. Ну или просто скопируйте и вставте строку что я привел как пример. "word_separators": "./()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#%^&*|+=[]{}`~?". А вообще работайте в IDE (PHPStorm например)